# Java Display ResultSet in Jtable

Tags: java, sql, jtable, resultset

I can only display first row on all my resultset in Jtable, but I can compute all the sum of related rows in resultset. I want to display all rows in Jtable. How?

```
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils; // use for jTable
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel; // use for jTable

private void showActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                     
PreparedStatement myStmt2;
PreparedStatement myStmt3;
PreparedStatement myStmt2a;
PreparedStatement myStmt3b;
PreparedStatement myStmt4;
PreparedStatement myStmt5;
String pizzatotalprice="0.00";
String drinkstotalprice="0.00";
String pizzatype="";
String pizzachosen="";
String topdetails="";
String crusttype="";
String pizzasize="";
String pizzaquantity="";
String drinkchosen="";
String drinksize="";
String drinkquantity="";
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)pizzaorderlist.getModel();
            try {
                 String query = "Select max(id) from customer ";

                 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pizzabaseaccount", "root", "");

                 Statement st = con.createStatement();

                 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                 rs.next();
                 String id = rs.getString("max(id)");


                 myStmt2= con.prepareStatement("Select *,sum(PizzaTotalPrice) from pizzaorder where ID = ? AND Confirmation='Unconfirmed' group by Customer");
                 myStmt2.setString(1,id);
                 ResultSet rs2 = myStmt2.executeQuery();
                   pizzaorderlist.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));
                 myStmt2a= con.prepareStatement("Select Customer,sum(PizzaTotalPrice) from pizzaorder where ID = ? AND Confirmation='Unconfirmed' group by Customer");
                 myStmt2a.setString(1,id);
                 ResultSet rs2a = myStmt2a.executeQuery();
                 if(rs2a.next())
                    pizzatotalprice = rs2a.getString("sum(PizzaTotalPrice)");

                 myStmt3= con.prepareStatement("Select *,sum(DrinksPrice) from drinkorder where id = ? AND Confirmation='Unconfirmed' group by Customer");
                 myStmt3.setString(1,id);
                 ResultSet rs3 = myStmt3.executeQuery();
                 drinksorderlist.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs3));

                 myStmt3b= con.prepareStatement("Select Customer,sum(DrinksPrice) from drinkorder where id = ? AND Confirmation='Unconfirmed' group by Customer");
                 myStmt3b.setString(1,id);
                 ResultSet rs3b = myStmt3b.executeQuery();
                 if(rs3b.next())
                    drinkstotalprice = rs3b.getString("sum(DrinksPrice)");
                 if(show.isSelected()){  
                 pizzaprice.setText(String.format("%.2f",Double.parseDouble(pizzatotalprice)));
                 drinksprice.setText(String.format("%.2f",Double.parseDouble(drinkstotalprice)));
                 price.setText(String.format("%.2f",Double.parseDouble(pizzatotalprice)+Double.parseDouble(drinkstotalprice)));
                 cancel.setEnabled(true);
                 confirm.setEnabled(true);
                 }

       //7th step
       con.close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();     
                }

// TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never iterate through your ResultSet properly. You should be using a while loop, and loop through the ResultSet until the `next()` method returns false. Within the loop, extract the data from that row of the ResultSet an use the data to create a new row for your TableModel.

Edit: I see via searching that this is a very common question on this site, and you can gain much be going through that search result: [java swing jtable resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+jtable+resultset)

Comment: give me codes sensei.... T__T